# Trying to understand why an EF Core InvalidOperationException happens in this situation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, entity-framework-core

I'm learning EF Core and I've hit an issue I can't quite understand why it happens:

Right now I have a view `PAYMENTSView` with a datagrid bound to a `List<PAYMETHOD> ACTIVEPAYMETHODs` property located on `PAYMENTSViewModel`.

When I instantiate a new `PAYMENTSView` I also set a `SALE CURRENT_SALE` property on its viewmodel. The user then selects a `PAYMETHOD`, `SelectedPayMethod`. Then it instantiates a new `PAYMENT` with `PAYMENT.PAYMETHOD = SelectedPayMethod`, and adds this new `PAYMENT` to `CURRENT_SALE.PAYMENTs`.

Then it calls `context.Update(CURRENT_SALE)` and `context.SaveChanges()`;

I've seen, at least here in SO, people saying that I shouldn't instantiate one `DbContext` for each access to the database (in this case one when filling `PAYMENTSView` and one when calling `Update` and `SaveChanges`), while others say I should stick to one context during the whole transaction (i.e. one new DbContext for each new `SALE`). Right now, I'm using multiple DbContext, so I *should* have any conflicts.

Now, to the issue: I can successfully instantiate one `SALE`, fill it, update and save it, alright. But when I try calling `Update` on another `SALE` that uses the same `PAYMETHOD`, I get this error:

> The instance of entity type 'PAYMETHOD' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked.

Now, I understand this happens because `PAYMETHOD` is already being tracked due to being used by the first `SALE`. I can bypass this issue by, rather than setting `PAYMENT.PAYMETHOD` setting `PAYMENT.PAYMETHOD_ID`. But I still want to understand why this happens. Since I've already called `Update`and `SaveChanges`, as well as instantiating new instances of both `SALE` and `PAYMENT`, shouldn't it be a different instance of `PAYMETHOD`, and hence, should have different tracking?

My relevant models are as follows:

```cs
public class SALE
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string PROPERTY1 {get;set;}
    public DateTime PROPERTY2 {get;set;}
    public List<PAYMENT> PAYMENTs {get;set;}
}

public class PAYMENT
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string PROPERTY3 {get;set;}
    public int PROPERTY4 {get;set;}
    #region FK
    public SALE SALE_PAYMENT {get;set;}
    public int SALE_PAYMENT_ID {get;set;}
    public PAYMETHOD PAYMETHOD_PAYMENT {get;set;}
    public int PAYMETHOD_PAYMENT_ID {get;set;}
    #endregion
}

public PAYMETHOD
{
    public int ID {get;set}
    public string PROPERTY5 {get;set}
    public bool PROPERTY6 {get;set;}
    public List<PAYMENT> PAYMENTs {get;set;}
}
```

Further information to reproduce it:

```
    ...
    <DataGrid IsTabStop="False" Grid.RowSpan="6" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ACTIVEPAYMETHODs}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    ...
    <TextBox Text="{Binding PAYMETHODCODE,StringFormat=C2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" KeyDown="txb_KeyDown"/>
    ...
```

```cs
public partial class PAYMENTSView : Window
{
    private void txb_ValorPagto_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            ((FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel)DataContext).ProcessPaymentMethod() == true    
    }
}

public class FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel
{
    public SALE CURRENT_SALE {get;set;}
    internal PAYMETHOD SelectedPayMethod {get;set;}
    public int PAYMETHODCODE
    {
        set
        {
            SelectedPayMethod = ACTIVEPAYMETHODs.Select(x=>x).Where(x=>x.ID == value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
    
    public PAYMENTSViewModel
    {
        ACTIVEPAYMETHODs = new List<PAYMETHOD>(_context
                    .PAYMETHODs
                    .Select(x => x)
                    .Where(x =>
                        x.STATUS == Status.Active)
                    .ToArray()
                    );
    }
    public void ProcessaMetodoAtual()
    {
        PAYMENT payment = new PAYMENT();
        payment.PAYMETHOD_PAYMENT = SelectedPayMethod;
        CURRENT_SALE.PAYMENTs.Add(payment);
        SelectedPayMethod = null;
        SaveToDatabase();
    }
    
    public void SaveToDatabase()
    {
        DbContext _context = new DbContextFactory().CreateDbContext();
        _context.Update(CURRENT_SALE);
        try
        {
        _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the actual relevant code if anyone wants to give it a look (after @ArwynFr changes): https://github.com/AKANexus/EFCoreQuestion/tree/master/AmbiStore

EDIT2: I forgot a very important piece of information: `CURRENT_SALE` is a new entity that hasn't been saved to the database yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why it happens

> Since I've already called Update and SaveChanges, as well as instantiating new instances of both SALE and PAYMENT, shouldn't it be a different instance of PAYMETHOD, and hence, should have different tracking?

It is a different instance of `PAYMETHOD`.

You have two entity instances, let's call them `PAYMETHOD__1` and `PAYMETHOD__2`. Each instance is tracked by a different context, let's call them `context__1` and `context__2`. However, the entities refer to the same database row, which means `PAYMETHOD__1.Id == PAYMETHOD__2.Id`.

This is a problem, because `context__1` is able to alter the entry in the database without `context__2` knowing. In that situation, `context__2` will consider `PAYMETHOD__2` to be clean, although the entity state is actually outdated and does not reflect changes made by `context__1` in the database. This can easily lead your application to alter your data in an inconsistent state.

A DbContext acts as an in-memory collection of entities, and it will keep track of changes you do on the entities in order to persist these changes to the database whenever you call `SaveChanges()`. You should always use a single instance of the context to handle, as long as you are operating in a coherent business transaction context. EF core detects you are doing something wrong with your contexts and throws an exception, rather than letting your application breaking your database.

## What you are doing wrong and how to fix it

The first thing to note  is that your code does a lot of mixing between models and viewmodels, and does not follow the principles of MVVM. The most notably wrong thing you are doing is setting the current sale to your viewmodel from the view, and the having your viewmodel instantiate a new DbContext.

If your application is already manipulating entities, especially a SALE object when the `FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel` is instanciated, then you already have a DbContext and that context instance **has** to be provided to the viewmodel so it can manipulate entities in a coherent context. You also either need to provide the SALE object, or it's Id. Since you set `CURRENT_SALE`, you already have the sale object so let's implement that :

```
public class FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private readonly SALE model;

    public FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel(DbContext context, SALE model)
    {
        this.context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        this.model = model ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
    }
}
```

Now we need to obtain the list of pay methods the user will choose among. Ideally, you should rather encapsulate your PAYMETHOD objects (models) into a PayMethodViewModel.

```
public class FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<PAYMETHOD> ACTIVEPAYMETHODs => context.PAYMETHODs
        .Where(method => method.STATUS == Status.Active)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Then let's handle the pay method selection by the user. Once again, this should rather be a viewmodel than an entity.

```
public class FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel
{
    private PAYMETHOD selectedPayMethod;
    public int PAYMETHODCODE
    {
        set
        {
            selectedPayMethod = ACTIVEPAYMETHODs
                .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Id == value);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, lets add the payment:

```
public class FECHAMENTOCUPOMViewModel
{
    public void ProcessaMetodoAtual()
    {
        PAYMENT payment = context.PAYMENTs.Add(new PAYMENT()
        {
            PAYMETHOD_PAYMENT = selectedPayMethod,
            SALE_PAYMENT = model // create the payment -> sale relationship
        }) as PAYMENT;
        model.PAYMENTs.Add(payment); // do not forget to add the inverse relationship
        context.SaveChanges(); // executes INSERT statement
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should always use ```Add()```, instead of ```Update()```, got it. Also, I got a conversion exception when creating ```PAYMENT```, as ```Add()``` returns an ```EntityEntry```, so I got the added ```PAYMENT``` accessing the ```Entity``` property. In which situations would I use ```Update(); SaveChanges()``` then?

Comment: Also, if I understood correctly, I should instantiate a new DbContext when I start a new sale, and keep it open, injecting it on the called methods as long as the sale is going on. That about right?

Comment: Ideally, I would suggest you use a single DbContext instance in your whole application, unless you have a very specific need to do so.

Comment: I would rather cast the entity using `as PAYMENT. It is better to manipulate strong typed objects because it allows to find errors at compile time rather than runtime. See edit.

Comment: What `Add()` does is marking an entity for insertion. `Update()` marks an entity for update. You also have `Remove()` that marks an entity for deletion. When you call `SaveChanges()`, DbContext will execute an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement for each marked entity.

Comment: DbContext also provides "tracking entities". When you query data from the DbContext, it will execute a SELECT statement (unless results already cached) and returns entities. If you modifiy a property, the entity is automatically marked for update and `SaveChanges()` will issue the UPDATE statement. Also, using property tracking allows DbContext to ignore properties without modification. Using `Update()` will lead to a full UPDATE statement, that will set all columns.

Comment: Tracking entities have an big performance cost, however. If you are in a readonly scenario, you can tell EF you are not interested in tracking changes. This can be done using `.AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: Decided to go all the way with MVVM architecture, so I'm rewriting everything to comply with MVVM policies.

Comment: @ASousa wishing you a good journey towards MVVM :)